# Convert Comma Seperated String to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a string which is -

```
str="Key=xxxx, age=11, key=yyyy , age=22,Key=zzzz, age=01, key=qqqq, age=21,Key=wwwww, age=91, key=pppp, age=22"
```

I want to convert this string to Python DataFrame with KEY and AGE as Column names.
The given key and age are in pair.
How could I achieve this conversion?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: Why some `Key` and some `key` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `regex`

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

s = "Key=xxxx, age=11, key=yyyy , age=22,Key=zzzz, age=01, key=qqqq, age=21,Key=wwwww, age=91, key=pppp, age=22"

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(re.findall(r'Key=([^,\s]+)', s, re.IGNORECASE), re.findall(r'age=([^,\s]+)', s, re.IGNORECASE)),
                 columns=['key', 'age'])

df
```

```
     key    age
0   xxxx    11
1   yyyy    22
2   zzzz    01
3   qqqq    21
4   wwwww   91
5   pppp    22
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex that find all pairs of `key/age` : `"key=(\w+)\s*,\s*age=(\w+)"` then use them to build the dataframe

```
import re
import pandas as pd

content = "Key=xxxx, age=11, key=yyyy , age=22,Key=zzzz, age=01, key=qqqq, age=21,Key=wwwww, age=91, key=pppp, age=22"
pat = re.compile(r"key=(\w+)\s*,\s*age=(\w+)", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

values = pat.findall(content)
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['key', 'age'])
print(df)

# - - - - - 
     key age
0   xxxx  11
1   yyyy  22
2   zzzz  01
3   qqqq  21
4  wwwww  91
5   pppp  22
```